# Loading Required JavaScript Files For Web

Tags: javascript, html, carousel, bower

I'm trying to load some required scripts for this [Carousel 3D](https://github.com/PAIO-CO-KR/carousel-3d). I'm not using NodeJS so I can't install Bower using NPM.  Where do I find these files for downloading?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/styles/jquery.carousel-3d.default.css">
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/javascript-detect-element-resize/jquery.resize.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/waitForImages/dist/jquery.waitforimages.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/jquery.carousel-3d.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find easily if you search those files in google.

Modernizr is very popular, you can find it in this [link](https://modernizr.com/)

The rest of the files are part of jquery library, very popular, you will find with google in less than a minute.

FYI: You can use the CDN files instead of downloading.